# How can I dynamically add/extend methods from a Class?

Tags: ruby, oop, class-method, instance-method

I'm using a Ruby Component inside an Audio Application Environment. This Ruby Component is represented by an instance of a `RubyEdit` class. This provide the interface between my Ruby code and the Environment.

For example if I write `self` it outputs the instance of the RubyEdit class that represents that component:

[image]

the nice things is that I can/must "implement/extend" some methods that `RubyEdit` will call when it get some events. I can define my custom method `event` for that instance:

```
def event
    # my own event code
end
```

and it will be called when the Environment get some events outside this Ruby Component. Or I can call a `class method` called `redraw`, and it will call my custom method `draw`:

```
  def draw
     # my own draw code (this will called after invoking redraw from Ruby Component)
  end
```

I need to understand some hierarchy of this process, so I'm making a simulation of that `RubyEdit` class in Ruby.

How it will looks? I mean: how can I provide methods that will be defined "later"?

This is how RubyEdit will look I think:

```
class RubyEdit
  def self.redraw
    # calling this class method should invoke my extended draw method
  end

  def draw
  end

  def event
  end
end
```

but I don't understand how to place `event` and `draw` methods extendible. Interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module ExtendRubyEdit

   def self.included(base)
     base.extend(ClassMethods)
   end

   def draw
   end

   def event
   end

   module ClassMethods
    def redraw
    end
   end
end

class RubyEdit
  include ExtendRubyEdit
end
```